# Can any one help me in writing a script for the following scenario

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Can any one help me in writing a script for the following scenario!!

- usera belongs to groupa and usera has access to "groupa" filesystem
- userb belongs to groupb and userb has access to "groupb" filesystem
- userc belongs to groupc and userc has access to "groupc" filesystem
- userd belongs to groupd and userd has access to "groupd" filesystem

Note:- group name and filesystem are identical.

Help me in writing a script, when a user logs in, group name to be identified and execute

```
df -h */group_name*
```

for example:- if usera logs in, then we need to o/p of "df -h /groupa"

```
[root@server5 ~]# df -h /groupa
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/groupa             601T  477T  125T  80% /groupa
[root@server5 ~]#
```

need to write a write by putting some logic, everytime a user login into the system, this script need to run and produce output on his/her terminal. We are trying to provide information to user about his filesystem utilization. This can be done by putting this script inside /etc/profile.d/ directory. user information can be taken from $USER variable and group information can be find out by "id -gn"

note:- some of the filesystem are like given below.

/filesystem/groupe

- usere belongs to groupe and usere has access to "/filesystem/groupe" filesystem

**I solved my problem by using the below given script:-**

```
grp=$(id -gn)
if [ "$grp" == "groupa" ]
then
    df -h /groupa
else
    if [ "$grp" == "groupb" ]
    then
        df -h /groupb
    else
        if [ "$grp" == "groupc" ]
        then
            df -h /groupc
        else
            if [ "$grp" == "groupd" ]
            then
                df -h /groupd
            else
                if [ "$grp" == "groupe" ]
                then
                    df -h /filesystem/groupe
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Try to describe your problem with something more relevant than "can any one help me in writing a script". What is your exact problem? What did you try? What problems are you facing? Also, writing `o/p` instead of `output` does look quite ugly

Comment: need to write a write by putting some logic, everytime a user login into the system, this script need to run and produce output on his/her terminal.

We are trying to provide information to user about his filesystem utilization.

This can be done by putting this script inside /etc/profile.d/ directory.

user information can be taken from $USER variable and group information can be find out by "id -gn"

Comment: Assuming they only belong to the one group,Put `df -h  */"$(groups)"*` in bashrc

Comment: Do not complement your question in comments. Instead, [edit] it and explain it properly. You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user3742796 What if a users **primary group** is set to something other than `group{abcde}`? It is common for a primary group to change. What then? Better to use `grp=$(id -Gn)` and then test if `group[abcde]` is within the groups returned.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to test to whether a user is a member of **group{a..z}** in bash. (**Note:** this is a bash only solution since it is using the `[[` construct and the `=~` operator). Using `id -Gn` also takes care of the situation where **group{a..z}** is not the **primary** group for the user, that would otherwise cause a search based on `id -gn` to fail:

```
#!/bin/bash

grps=$(id -Gn)              ## return a list of groups of which user is a member

for i in group{a..z}; do    ## for i in groupa, groupb, groupc, ..., groupz

    ## test if groupX is in the list $umg
    #  on match get disk usage of /groupX
    [[ $grps =~ $i ]] && du -hs /$i

done
```